# Why does Java require annotation values to be qualified in annotations but not in switch statements?

Tags: javac, jls

In Java, `Enum` constants in a `switch` statement do not require (or even allow) the constants to be type-qualified.

Example:

```
switch (obj.getEnumValue()) {
case VALUE1:
  ...
case VALUE2:
  ...
}
```

This is possible of course because the `Enum` type is known at compile time.

However, the same convenience is not afforded to `Enum` values when used within annotations, even though the `Enum` type is known at compile time there too:

Example:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)     // compile error here!
public @interface MyAnnotation {
   ...
}
```

My question is why does the JLS treat these two cases differently? I'm trying to understand the reasoning from a language design perspective.

It seems like the same logic would apply in both cases: the `Enum` type is known, so the language should allow (or even require) the `Enum` constants to be unqualified, for the sake of brevity and programmer convenience.

PS. This is not a question about how to workaround the issue. This is a JLS design question.

Comment: *Because the specification says so*. I know, this is not a satisfying answer, but there doesn’t have to be a rationale behind this. It might be possible, that the `switch` statement rules and the annotation rules were defined by a different developers. I could immediately raise some more questions, e.g. why `enum` constants are not treated like compile-time constants…